# Creating ts objects in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have only started playing around with time series in R so I have fallen at the first hurdle! I have a vector of daily temperature readings (with no date stamp) and I am having problems creating such an object.

```
data<-rnorm(3650, m=10, sd=2)
data_ts<-as.ts(data, frequency=365, start=c(1919, 1))
attributes(data_ts)
dcomp<-decompose(data_ts, type=c("additive"))
```

I think this code should be instructing R to make a ts object with daily measurements (frequency=365) starting at 1-1-1919. I dont understand the error message in the decompose command, I have a feeling I have not created the ts object correctly because data_ts$tsp does not look correct!

Answer (score 2):

```
data <- rnorm(3650, m=10, sd=2)
# change is below, use ts() to create time series
data_ts <- ts(data, frequency=365, start=c(1919, 1))
attributes(data_ts)
dcomp<-decompose(data_ts, type=c("additive"))
plot(dcomp)
```

Produces:

[image: Time series decomposed]

Comment: Why is frequency=365, because of leap year every four years aren't there technically 365.25 days per year?

Comment: @MikeTP: you are technically correct, of course. The `frequency` argument in `ts()` refers to the "the number of observations per unit of time", not to the actual time period itself. In this example, the issue makes no real difference.